# Print name of the default math font?

Tags: fonts

This should be easy. But it's not easy to find. MWE:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\rmdefault\par
\sfdefault\par
\ttdefault\par
% What prints the math default font(s)? Expecting lmm.
\end{document}
```

Above prints lmr, lmss, lmtt for the three text fonts. Good.

I would like the document to print the name(s) of the default math font. If necessary I can enter and exit math mode for the command, but I do not actually need to use the math font there. And, I'm not interested in looking in the PDF for its list of fonts. I know what the math font is. Getting its name to print in the document, is the question.

Comment: math uses (without unicode math) a number of fonts, so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps MWE is too minimal! Actual purpose of my question: I wish to know whether the `\setmathfont` command was used, without hacking the code for that command. I can do this for `\setmainfont` by string comparison of `\rmdefault` to `lmr`.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear even after the comments, `\setmathfont` isn't even defined unless `unicode-math` has been used, so clearly not been used in that case (and if `uniocde-math` is loaded then the default fonts are changed to latin modern math)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops. My MWE was too minimal. I am indeed using unicode-math. Will modify MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\rmdefault\par
\sfdefault\par
\ttdefault\par

$x$

\fontname\textfont0\par
\fontname\textfont1\par
\fontname\textfont2\par
\fontname\textfont3\par

% What prints the math default font(s)? Expecting lmm.
\end{document}
```

this is the primitive layer font name, not an NFSS axis name in the style of `\rmfamily`

With `unicode-math` by default you will get

[image]

Comment: Great! I can take it from there. This is related to the issue I raised earlier this week, regarding l3 and my hacked fontspec code. I am now un-hacking my code. Works, but I didn't know how to get at the math part (I don't do math, myself).

Comment: @RobtA everybody should do math!

Comment: Oh all right, I'll do a little math. I notice that your solution requires something to be printed in math mode, before the math textfonts are set. I discovered that this works in Preamble: `\newlength\widthofmathx` then `\setlength\widthofmathx{\widthof{\(x\)}}`. That sets the math textfonts, without actually printing anything. Then I can read the textfont strings in Preamble, and execute code based on which fonts were set. Incidentally, in my document class a dollar is a dollar, not math mode.

Comment: @RobtA no, not in the preamble (if you are using unicode-math) you have to set it up after begin{document}

Comment: Ah, that helps! I had it working, then not working... It had to do with where I put it.